# How to display facebook number of friends + profile picture in Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I have a simple Meteor app where users can sign in via Facebook. After logging in, the only 2 things that appear by default are user's name and a sign out button.

How do I make it possible to render user's facebook profile photo + the number of user's friends after logging in?

I know I need to use:

```
    {{#if currentUser}} {{/if}}
```

but I really don't know what code to add in between those brackets.

Tried to add:

```
    {{currentUser.services.facebook.avatar}}
```

but it's not working. I have also tried something like:

```
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{currentUser.services.facebook}}/picture?wudth=200&height=200">
```

I honestly tried to find a duplicate issue of this but really couldn't. Please help.

Comment: The `services` property is not published by default. Publishing the services property is not recommended, since it could contain personal data (like email addresses and auth tokens). You could copy the data you want to make public to the user's profile and reference that.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I understand what exactly to do as I'm a beginner when it comes to Meteor platform. But thanks, I'll spend some time to search again.

Answer (score 0):

you should use facebook.id in your image lookup like:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/" + user.services.facebook.id + "/picture?width=200&height=200"
```

or in a template:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{user.services.facebook.id}}/picture?width=200&height=200">
```